# Triggering an existing segue programmatically (Automatically)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I have an existing segue linked to a button.  I would like the button and segue to remain but need a way to trigger the segue programmatically in my view did load after a successful IF statement. The segue was created using storyboard.

I tried performing **performSegueWithIdentifier** but there is no "self sender" because there is no UI being triggered.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Is there a simple way to do this? No phantom buttons or forcing the existing button to execute.

Comment: The code you have shown is correct.  You probably want to do it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`

Comment: **GREAT!** that was the problem.  I was putting it in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: small question, if i want to performsegue entirely from code and not from storyboard, how can I do it? Secondly, if I delete the segue from Storyboard the app crashes when i do the [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:self];

Answer (score 0):

A segue does not require a user interaction to be triggered. The `sender` is the object that the `prepareForSegue` method will receive.

Using `self` is actually the correct way because it means the view controller triggered the segue and not a view object.

If you have no use for the `sender` in `prepareForSegue` then keep the call as-is and ignore it in the implementation.

Also, this call will not work in `viewDidLoad` since the view in still not the in windows hierarchy. You should wait until after `viewDidAppear` before performing any segues.